# delete files with partial match to another list of names

Tags: bash, unix

I have a list of names in file1 that is a substring of the true filenames of the files I want to delete. I want to delete the files that are partially matched by the names in file1. Any idea how to specify the files to delete?

file1:

```
  file123
  file313
  file355
```

True files:

```
  file123.sam.out
  file313.sam.out
  file355.sam.out
  file342455.sam.out
  file34455.sam.out
```

Files to keep:

```
  file342455.sam.out
  file34455.sam.out
```

Comment: Note that filenames _are allowed to have newlines in them_, so using one-name-per-line as a format for processing lists of names has its risks.

Comment: That said, this looks like a very clear-cut job for `grep`. Have you made any starting attempts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you don't have any filenames containing newline literals...

```
printf '%s\n' * | grep -Fvf file1 | xargs -d $'\n' rm -f --
```

Let's walk through this piece-by-piece:

- `printf '%s\n' *` generates a list of files in your current directory.
- `grep -Fvf file1` removes from that list any string that contains as a substring a line from `file1`
- `xargs -d $'\n' rm -f --` splits its stdin on newlines, and passes anything it's left as an argument to `rm -f --`

---

If you have GNU tools (and a shell, like bash, with process substitution support), you can use NUL delimiters and thus work with all possible filenames:

```
printf '%s\0' * |
  grep -zFvf <(tr '\n' '\0' <file1) |
  xargs -0 rm -f --
```

- `printf '%s\0' *` puts a NUL, instead of a newline, after each filename.
- `tr '\n' '\0' <file1` emits the contents of file1 with newlines replaced with NULs
- `grep -zFvf` reads both its inputs as NUL-delimited, and writes NUL-delimited output, but otherwise behaves as above.
- `xargs -0 rm -f --` reads content, splitting on NULs, and passes input as arguments to `rm -f --`.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash

PATTERN_FILE=file1
FILE_TO_REMOVE_FOLDER=files

cat $PATTERN_FILE | while read x
do
    if [ "" != "$x" ]
    then
        echo "rm $FILE_TO_REMOVE_FOLDER/$x*"
        rm $FILE_TO_REMOVE_FOLDER/$x*
    fi
done
```

Comment: yes, 3 are deleted and 2 are kept

Comment: Why `cat $PATTERN_FILE |`, instead of `done <"$PATTERN_FILE"`? You're `fork()`ing off a subshell, and scoping variables changed inside it so they can't be seen after the loop exits.

Comment: ...beyond that, I don't see how this is accomplishing the thing the OP asked for.